# Use external plugin in Android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

There is plugin named **`Git Flow Integration`** for Intellij and Android Studio.

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/OpherV/gitflow4idea).

When I search for this plugin under `Android Studio > Settings > Plugins` option. plugin is not listed but plugin External jar is available [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7315?pr=androidstudio).

There is plugins folder in android studio but where i have to put this file?

After adding file in plugins folder how can i use it and why i can not find this plugin in Android studio?

**EDIT:**

I have tried `Setting --> Plugin --> Install Plugin from Disk` but it gives me this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Click on the browse will give you the below screen

[image]

you can install the non bundled plugin

> Happy codding

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own custom plugin in Android Studio and Intellij IDEA platform using the **Setting** --> **Plugin** --> **Install Plugin from Disk**

https://github.com/magnetsystems/rest2mobile/wiki/Install-the-plugin-in-Android-Studio

Comment: Thanks for quick response but it is showing plugin is incompatible with this installation